# Images and captions don't align

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a section of a page to look like this
[image: How it's supposed to look]

However I keep getting stuck with it looking like this
[image]

Please help still fairly new!!

**HTML**

```
  <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>
    <h4>What's Sleeping at The Tea Cozy?</h4>

    <div class="tea">
            <div class="images">
                    <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt=”berryblitz”>
                <p>Fall BerryBlitz Tea </p>
            </div>
            <div class="images">
                <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-spiced-rum.jpg" alt=”spicedrum”>
            <p>Fall BerryBlitz Tea </p>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-donut.jpg" alt=”Donuts”>
        <p>Fall BerryBlitz Tea </p>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-myrtle-ave.jpg" alt=”myrtleave”>
        <p>Fall BerryBlitz Tea </p>
    </div>
    <div class="images">
        <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg" alt=”myrtleave”>
    <p>Fall BerryBlitz Tea </p>
</div>


    
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tea{   width: 1000px;
     height: auto;   
     margin: 10px auto; 
}  

.images{ height: 200px; 
         width: 300px;    
         display:inline-flex; 
        margin: 10px 10px; 
}
```

I tried a couple of different things but I am at a lose. Any help or advice would be appreciated

Comment: There are several ways to implement what you are trying to do.  I would look into figure and figure caption in HTML. To get more complicated, I would look more into CSS Grid or CSS libraries to help like Bootstrap. 
But a kind of short cut, can be implemented that wouldn't be very reactive to mobile or other sizes of the website but you can make all of the  paragraph elements ''p'' as display: block; in css.

Comment: What would be best for a mobile version

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.tea {   
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;   
  margin: 10px auto; 
  display: inline-flex;
}  
.images{ 
  height: 200px; 
  width: 300px;    
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px 10px; 
}
.images p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Here's the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOhId.png)

You can further arrange the `.images` divs by enable `flex-wrap` and define the `gap` between them!

Comment: Thanks for the info I’ll try it out and see how it comes out!!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it like this

```
.tea{
width: 1000px;
height: auto;   
margin: 10px auto; 
.images{
height: 200px; 
width: 300px;    
display: inline-flex;
margin: 10px 10px;
flex-direction: column;
padding-top: 50px;
```

}